# Make install puts module in wrong kernel version directory

Tags: kernel, raspbian, v4l2loopback

```
sudo make install
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/pi/v4l2loopback modules_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/5.15.32-v8+/linux-60652604154e70aeac81fb6155fd9d15dc39daaf'
  INSTALL /lib/modules/5.15.21-v8+/extra/v4l2loopback.ko
  DEPMOD  /lib/modules/5.15.21-v8+
Warning: modules_install: missing 'System.map' file. Skipping depmod.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/5.15.32-v8+/linux-60652604154e70aeac81fb6155fd9d15dc39daaf'

SUCCESS (if you got 'SSL errors' above, you can safely ignore them)
```

Turns out that there are a bunch of files on /lib/modules/5.15.32-v8+ which have the wrong version number:

```
cd /lib/modules/5.15.32-v8+/build
grep -R 5.15.21
include/config/auto.conf.cmd:ifneq "$(KERNELVERSION)" "5.15.21"
include/config/auto.conf:# Linux/arm64 5.15.21 Kernel Configuration
include/config/kernel.release:5.15.21-v8+
include/generated/autoconf.h: * Linux/arm64 5.15.21 Kernel Configuration
include/generated/utsrelease.h:#define UTS_RELEASE "5.15.21-v8+"
arch/arm64/kernel/vdso/vdso.lds: * Linux/arm64 5.15.21 Kernel Configuration
.config:# Linux/arm64 5.15.21 Kernel Configuration
```

Once I change these numbers, the module goes to the right location.

I don't know whom to report this - Did this come from the rpi-source utility from the raspberry pi, or some deb package?

Comment: `/lib/modules/5.15.32-v8+/build` should be a symbolic link - where does it point to? (`ls -l /lib/modules/5.15.32-v8+/build`, please) Also, if you were in fact running 5.15.21 still while building a module for 5.15.32, it might be a bug in the `v4l2loopback` module's build process, as suggested by the presence of `uname -r` in the `make` output.

Comment: I have the impression that rpi-source is downloading the wrong kernel. When I ditched the rpi-source kernel and simply did an `apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`, I was able to make it compile cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

rpi-source downloads the wrong kernel. Using `apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers` brings the needed headers to compile this module.